# mem_test.bat file does not execute

Tags: hardware, fpga, xilinx

I am in the middle of designing a schematic in Xilinx ISE 14.7 **core generator** and I've run into a little problem which I need help with. I need to run mem_edit.bat file in order to run the **memory editor** application and create a ***.coe*** file. Whenever I run the file, command prompt just flashes on the screen without running the commands. How do I run ***mem_edit.bat*** to be able to run memory test. I have run the file in a static command prompt session and inserted  a pause in the code to no avail. I have also run the commands directly in command prompt and still no success. Please help me as I am on a timeline and I need to finish this fast. I am running on a 64 bit windows10 machine. I am kinda new to Xilinx ISE so please go a bit easy on me.  The contents of ***mem_edit.bat*** have been quoted below

```
@echo off
REM Script to launch Xilinx memory editor

set CLASSPATH=
set JAVA_HOME=

"%XILINX%\java\nt64\jre\bin\java" -DXILINX="%XILINX%" -DMYXILINX="%MYXILINX%"  -cp "%XILINX%\coregen\lib\encore.jar;%XILINX%\coregen\lib\coreutil.jar;%XILINX%\coregen\lib\sim.jar;%XILINX%\coregen\lib\xcc.jar;%XILINX%\coregen\lib;%XILINX%\coregen\resources" com.xilinx.iputils.memory.editor.CoreGen2RunMemoryEditor 2> NUL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue. I happened to stumble on the directory where the ISE cmd short cut is saved **`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Xilinx Design Tools 1\ISE Design Suite 14.7\Accessories`**. I run the file and Kaboom, the ISE cmd fired up. I entered `mem_edit.bat` and the application is up and running.